# Train passenger delayed probability

Tags: probability

I am trying to create a formula for deciding how many passanger will be affected by a delayed train here is the data that is know to me:

each year **350.000** passengers take the train.

Each year an average of **5548** train delays.

At any given time there are **104** trains in transit

Each train has a max capacity of **340** passengers

Now I wish to figure out approximately how many passengers are onboard one of the delayed trains

I assume that this is tricky since we need some kind of probability of being delayed first?

Comment: How many trains are needed to transport all the 350.000 passengers?

Comment: I think you need to assume more things. With your current hypothesis, I can just say on January 1, 350000 passengers take the first train, and that train is delayed, so all 350000 passengers are affected?

Comment: I will try find out how many trains run each year would that help?

Comment: @Pspl ive updated my question

Comment: do all 350000 passengers take the train every day? or like an average of 300000 passengers-ish take the train in any given day?

Comment: @VladimirPutin 350k take the train each year (so a sum of 350k passengers)

Comment: @MarcRasmussen, that's not enough. You really need to know how many $n$ trains are needed. Then, assuming that each train transports $\frac{350000}{n}$, the answer to your problem is $\frac{350000}{n}\times5548$.

Comment: @Pspl it takes around 104 trains to transport 350.000 passengers where each train can carry 340 passengers. Then we need to figure out how many are delayed

Comment: @MarcRasmussen, again: you have to find how many trains in total. The conditions you gave aren't enough to determine that number.

Comment: @Pspl if there are 104 trains in transit then it must be 104*365 = 37960 each year

Comment: @MarcRasmussen, saying there are 104 trains in transit at any given time are COMPLETELY different than saying there are 104 trains per day. Which statement do you prefer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99907/discussion-between-marc-rasmussen-and-pspl).